# Struct char variable that is assigned in a void function, printing garbage in the main function

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, char

I've defined a struct with `typedef` that is called `Node`. One of it's member is the `key` which is a pointer of the `char` type so that I can assign a value to it dynamically.

The header file for `Node` is `cnode.h`

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Node {
    char *key;
    int value;
    Node *next = NULL;
    
} Node;

void print_node(Node x){
    printf("[%s, %d]\n",x.key, x.value);
    
}

void print_list(Node head){
    printf("\n");
    while (head.next !=NULL){
        print_node(head);
        head = *head.next;
        printf("-->");
    }
    print_node(head);
}
```

Now I'm declaring the Node as `set[SIZE]`. I'm trying to create a `set` like structure for accessing value nearly O(1) time.

The location of my insertion is computed by a hash function. I'm inserting the value by an external function `void insert()`.

For sanity check I'm printing the value of `key` both in the `insert()` function and `main()` function. But the result is not same in the both functions.

Here is the main program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cnode.h"

#define CAPACITY 50

unsigned long hash_function(int x)
{
    unsigned long i;
    i = x*(x+3)+x; //Knuth Variant on Division
    return i % CAPACITY;
}



void insert(Node *set, int value){
    char key[20];
 
    sprintf(key, "%d", value);

    int loc = hash_function(value);
    
    set[loc].key = key;
    set[loc].value = value;
 
    print_node(set[loc]);

}

int main(){
    Node set[CAPACITY];

    insert(set, 18);
    insert(set, 122);
    
    printf("\nVALIDATION\n");
    print_node(set[46]);
    print_node(set[22]);

}
```

I'm compiling my code with `g++`.

```
g++ -o main main.c && ./main
```

The output:

```
[18, 18]
[122, 122]

VALIDATION
[�7�H�, 18]
[�7�H�, 122]
```

I've tried many thing with pointer and address. But still I couldn't fix the garbage output. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope) `set[loc].key = key;` saves a pointer to a local variable, and then you try to use it after the local variable has been destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
set[loc].key = key;
```

key is a temporary value that will be deleted after the function completes.

What you want to do is use malloc to allocate permanent memory

```
char *newkey = (char *)malloc(16*sizeof(char)); // allocate room for 16 characters
sprintf(newkey, "%d", value);¨
set[loc].key = newkey;
```

Comment: why are you multiplying by 16?

Comment: Because 16 characters seems to be enough to print an integer. 12 may also be enough but I did not want to risk anything. Too little room and the program would crash!